# SQL Server 2017 - get column name, datatype and value of table

Tags: sql-server

I thought it was a simple task but it's a couple of hours I'm still struggling :-(

I want to have the list of column names of a table, together with its datatype and the value contained in the columns, but have no idea how to bind the table itself to get the current value:

```
DECLARE @TTab TABLE
(
    fieldName     nvarchar(128),
    dataType      nvarchar(64),
    currentValue  nvarchar(128)
)

INSERT INTO @TTab (fieldName,dataType)
    SELECT
        i.COLUMN_NAME,
        i.DATA_TYPE
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i
    WHERE 
        i.TABLE_NAME = 'Users'
```

Expected result:

```
+------------+----------+---------------+
| fieldName  | dataType | currentValue  |
+------------+----------+---------------+
| userName   | nvarchar | John          |
| active     | bit      | true          |
| age        | int      | 43            |
| balance    | money    | 25.20         |
+------------+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: What happens what you have more than 1 row?

Comment: You're mixing two very distinct set of "things" - the column name and its datatype (and max length etc.) are all **meta data** of the table - data describing the table structure - while the current value is the actual useful data inside the table. I don't think you can easily combine these two very distinct sets of data in a single query .... and why should you? What's the "current value" if you have a table of hundreds of rows??

Comment: I agree, the "current value" bit makes no sense. A column in a table does not have a single value.

Comment: well, I did not add that piece of code because I thought was not relevant, but clearly the query will also have a where clause like `"where users.userid=@userid"` to filter data in way to have only one row

Comment: I avoided to mention `max-length` and other properties too, although need to extract, since such data just require to add a field in the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the answer is: No, this is impossible. But there is a hack using text-based containers like XML or JSON (v2016+):

--Let's create a test table with some rows

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestGetMetaData(ID INT IDENTITY,PreName VARCHAR(100),LastName NVARCHAR(MAX),DOB DATE);
INSERT INTO dbo.TestGetMetaData(PreName,LastName,DOB) VALUES
 ('Tim','Smith','20000101')
,('Tom','Blake','20000202')
,('Kim','Black','20000303')
GO
```

--Here's the query

```
SELECT C.colName
      ,C.colValue
      ,D.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT t.* FROM dbo.TestGetMetaData t
    WHERE t.Id=2
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
) A(rowSet)
CROSS APPLY A.rowSet.nodes('*') B(col)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(B.col.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(500)')
                  ,B.col.value('text()[1]',   'nvarchar(max)'))) C(colName,colValue)
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS D ON    D.TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
                                        AND  D.TABLE_NAME='TestGetMetaData'
                                        AND  D.COLUMN_NAME=C.colName;

GO
```

--Clean-Up (**carefull with real data**)

```
DROP TABLE dbo.TestGetMetaData;
GO
```

Part of the result

```
+----------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------+
| colName  | colValue   | DATA_TYPE | CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH | IS_NULLABLE |
+----------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------+
| ID       | 2          | int       | NULL                     | NO          |
+----------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------+
| PreName  | Tom        | varchar   | 100                      | YES         |
+----------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------+
| LastName | Blake      | nvarchar  | -1                       | YES         |
+----------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------+
| DOB      | 2000-02-02 | date      | NULL                     | YES         |
+----------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+-------------+
```

The idea in short:

- Using `FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE` will create a XML representing your SELECT's result set.
- The big advantage with this: The XML's element will carry the column's name.
- We can use a `CROSS APPLY` to geht the column's name and value
- Now we can `JOIN` the metadata from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

One hint: All values will be of type `nvarchar(max)` actually.
The value being a string type might lead to unexpected results due to implicit conversions or might lead into troubles with BLOBs.

**UPDATE**

The following query wouldn't even need to specify the table's name in the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT C.colName
      ,C.colValue
      ,D.DATA_TYPE,D.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,IS_NULLABLE
FROM 
(
        SELECT * FROM dbo.TestGetMetaData 
        WHERE Id=2
        FOR XML AUTO,TYPE
) A(rowSet)
CROSS APPLY A.rowSet.nodes('/*/@*') B(attr)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(A.rowSet.value('local-name(/*[1])','nvarchar(500)')
                  ,B.attr.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(500)')
                  ,B.attr.value('.',   'nvarchar(max)'))) C(tblName,colName,colValue)
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS D ON    CONCAT(D.TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',D.TABLE_NAME)=C.tblName
                                        AND  D.COLUMN_NAME=C.colName;
```

Why?
Using `FOR XML AUTO` will use *attribute centered* XML. The elements name will be the tables name, while the values rest within attributes.

**UPDATE 2**

Fully generic function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetRowWithMetaData(@input XML)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT C.colName
      ,C.colValue
      ,D.*
FROM @input.nodes('/*/@*') B(attr)
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(@input.value('local-name(/*[1])','nvarchar(500)')
                  ,B.attr.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(500)')
                  ,B.attr.value('.',   'nvarchar(max)'))) C(tblName,colName,colValue)
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS D ON    CONCAT(D.TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',D.TABLE_NAME)=C.tblName
                                        AND  D.COLUMN_NAME=C.colName;
```

--You call it like this (see the extra paranthesis!)

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetRowWithMetaData((SELECT * FROM dbo.TestGetMetaData WHERE ID=2 FOR XML AUTO));
```

As you see, the function does not even has to know anything in advance...

Comment: Wow!
too complicated for my basic skills :-(

Hope to be able to fix the function since D.* are all NULL (while in the **UPDATE** it returns correct values)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joe be sure not to use any table alias in your select. `Xml auto` relies on the table's name as provided

Comment: @Joe Just a hint: You might include `C.tblName` to the result and check if this table name is the same as `schema` + '.' + 'table'. If not the LEFT JOIN will return without a result.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @Charlieface well, yeah ... Talking about tables with names I'd use some shortened alias pointing to the entity behind. But in cases, where we just add some computed columns to the set A, B C gives a hint to the order of `APPLY`s...

Comment: @Shnugo Sorry, function works perfectly: I wrote `FROM Users WHERE ... FOX XML` and got null results but with `dbo.Users` returns the right data